# Каким образом JavaScript-методы, не работающие с каким-либо типом данных, начинают работать с ним при подмене контекста?

Tags: javascript

В частности ...

Метод `Math.max()` НЕ принимает в качестве аргумента массив.

Почему он начинает его принимать и обрабатывать в связке с `.apply()`:

```
Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

Если `Math.max()` в своём исходном коде определяет массив был передан или нет, то зачем тогда `.apply()`?

Comment: `Math.max.apply(array);` неверная запись. первый параметр должен быть контекстом, в случае с Math - это может быть null

Comment: @Grundy, да, конечно,.. это я и имел в виду, но опечатался. Поправил.

Comment: С чем работали, с тем и будут работать. Просто `Function#apply` разворачивает массив в аргументы. Если не нужно подменять контекст, то лучше использовать `Spread` оператор.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: @Suvitruf, если бы мне был дан бы исчерпывающий ответ, я отметил бы его как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что по спецификации [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.max) `Math.max` принимает список аргументов.

А [apply](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply) вызывает функцию с указанным значением this и аргументами, предоставленными в виде массива.

`Math.max("1", "2", "3")` - это тоже самое, что :

```
var list = ["1", "2", "3"];
Math.max.apply(null, list);
```

В ECMAScript ES6  ещё можно использовать [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Examples):

```
var list = ["1", "2", "3"];
Math.max(...list);
```

Comment: _`Math.max("1", "2", "3")` - это тоже самое, что: `Math.max.apply(list);`_ - нет, это не то же самое

Comment: @Grundy, как и у автора очепятка. Не будьте столь строги :)

Comment: @Other, автор уже поправил :-)

Comment: @Grundy, у ответа пинг большой :)

Comment: @Other у меня GMT +9 (:

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `Math.max` не получает массив.

В этом виновата функция:

> Function.prototype.apply(context, arguments);

Она реализована так, что передаваемый массив аргументов будет передан исходной функции, по одному:

```js
function test(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
  console.log(a1, a2, a3, a4);
}


test.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]); // 1 2 3 undefined
test(1, 2, 3); // 1 2 3 undefined
```

Таким образом Math.max, не знает, что мы ищем максимум в массиве - мы просто передали ей **все** элементы массива по отдельности, с помощью `apply`.

```js
function max(/*args*/) {
  var maxValue = -Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    if (arguments[i] > maxValue) {
      maxValue = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return maxValue;
}

console.log(max(5, -2, 8, 3));
console.log(max.apply(null, [5, -2, 8, 3]));
```